# Reuse already loaded JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

### The goal

Reuse already loaded JavaScript correctly.

### The problem

I'm generating a map dynamically using Google Maps API V3 and I need to reuse it. **How?**

### The scenario

On *Index.html*, there's the following script:

```
var gMapsLoaded = false;

window.gMapsCallback = function () {
    gMapsLoaded = true;
    $(window).trigger('gMapsLoaded');
}

window.loadGoogleMaps = function () {
    if (gMapsLoaded) return window.gMapsCallback();
    var script_tag = document.createElement('script');
    script_tag.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
    script_tag.setAttribute("src", 
        "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=gMapsCallback");
    (document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]
     || document.documentElement).appendChild(script_tag);
}
```

When I click on some button to show the map, my app invokes this script:

```
[...]

var geocoder;
var map;
var address = context.address();

function initialize() {
    var mapDiv = document.getElementById("map_canvas");
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 15,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeControl: true,
        mapTypeControlOptions: 
           { style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU },
        navigationControl: true,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, myOptions);

    if (geocoder) {
        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                if (status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {
                    map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

                    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
                        {
                            content: '<b>' + address + '</b>',
                            size: new google.maps.Size(150, 50)
                        });

                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: results[0].geometry.location,
                        map: map,
                        title: address
                    });

                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                        infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    });

                } else {
                    alert("No results found");
                }
            } else {
                alert
                    ("Geocode was not successful 
                     for the following reason: " + status);
            }
        });
    }

    gMapsLoaded = false;
}

$(window).on('gMapsLoaded', initialize);
window.loadGoogleMaps();
```

As you can see, the application is always calling the `loadGoogleMaps();` function that calls the external `.js` file. If I click in the 5 different maps, I get 5 scripts with the same proposal.

**Someone have any idea to solve this?**

### Duplicated question?

Yes, I think that the essence of the question is duplicated, but the nucleus isn't.

Comment: show the code for initialize(), you might be re-dispatching there...

Comment: Done, @dandavis. The code is posted.

Comment: hmmm, what is the name of the script file that is being loaded 5 times? if it's the same file it should be cached and not a waste of bandwidth, but it would be best to avoid if possible...

Comment: Here's the problem: `gMapsLoaded = false;` Don't do that.

Comment: also, just call the functions instead of using trigger with an event name the same as a boolean, that's confusing as all getout...

Comment: This is the file: `http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=gMapsCallback`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As you can see, the application is always calling the
>   loadGoogleMaps(); function that calls the external .js file. If I
>   click in the 5 different maps, I get 5 scripts with the same proposal.

That is incorrect. After the first time it completely loads, the if statement on the first line will return early, preventing you from including it multiple times.

There's nothing wrong with the way that's written.

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vYksD/)

```
var gMapsLoaded = false;

window.gMapsCallback = function () {
    gMapsLoaded = true;
    $(window).trigger('gMapsLoaded');
}

window.loadGoogleMaps = function () {
    if (gMapsLoaded) return window.gMapsCallback();
    console.log('Generating new script tag');
    var script_tag = document.createElement('script');
    script_tag.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
    script_tag.setAttribute("src", 
        "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=gMapsCallback");
    (document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]
     || document.documentElement).appendChild(script_tag);
}

$(window).on("gMapsLoaded",function(){
    console.log("gMapsLoaded");
});
$(function(){
    $("button").on("click",window.loadGoogleMaps);
});
```

Now, if you were to click it 5 times really fast when it isn't already loaded, it could potentially load it multiple times. You should call that function on it's own before a click event would normally happen to prevent that.

---

**Update:**

At the end of your `initialize()` method, you're using `gMapsLoaded = false;` which causes the above code to once again request a new script tag. Simply remove/comment out that line.

Comment: I can't call that function before a click event because the methods used by the click trigger doesn't recognize the methods passed by the Google Maps Api. And contrary to what you said, even if I wait 60 seconds, the application calls the script again.

Comment: Something must be going on unrelated to the code you posted, everything works correctly in fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/vYksD/ It only loads the script once, subsequent clicks to the button simply execute the loaded callback.

Comment: But Kevin, I need to render the map each time that I click on the button. Its work if I don't set `gMapsLoaded = false;` at the bottom of the `initialize()` method.

Comment: If you do `gMapsLoaded = false;` it will ALWAYS request another script. Either don't do it, or accept it requesting another script. I don't understand what this has to do with rendering the map each time.

Comment: If you want to re-render the map, re-render the map. that shouldn't require you re-including the entire library again.

Comment: Look, @KevinB, you're right: if I do `gMapsLoaded = false;`, I always will request another script. BUT, if I don't do `gMapsLoaded = false;`, the map isn't rendered again, can you understand me? What I want is conceptually simple: render the map for the first time. If the map is already rendered before, then reuse the API script and render it again. *I'm not getting to apply this logic!*

Comment: Ok then. Lets focus on THAT then. There is no reason to re-load the api script, therefore you should not do `gMapsLoaded = false`. Now that that is squared away, lets figure out why your map isn't re-rendering.

Comment: Can you post a sample of your click event that causes the map to re-render?

Comment: Here's a re-creation of all the code you've posted thus far: http://jsfiddle.net/vYksD/1/ the map isn't showing up for me though.

Comment: I debugged a little more and the `initialize()` method is always called. Based on this fact, then we can say  that there's no problem here. If we go forward, we can conclude that the map doesn't render because... well, I don't know. No error messages, the `initialize()` function is called... What I could observe is that the div that is generated within the `#map_canvas` is removed when I call the map twice, but nothing happens beyond this.

Comment: The map appears to be re-rendering here when i click the button again: http://jsfiddle.net/vYksD/3/

Comment: I think I found a problem. When I click for the second time on the (click) trigger, the map is called two times. There's something wrong with the trigger — of course there is. @KevinB Your concept helped me a lot. Just a second, I'll try a few things here..

Comment: Yes, the `initialize()` method is called twice and now I know why. The `$(window).on("gMapsLoaded",initialize);` is within the `$(button).on("click", function() { ... }` in the case of my app. To better comprehension, take a look on [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vYksD/5/). So, I have to call `$(window).on("gMapsLoaded",initialize);` in somewhere, but... Where?

Comment: So every time you click, you're binding another handler to the gMapsLoaded event. That would explain weirdness, not sure if it would explain the map not re-rendering though.

Comment: I tried to place the initializer on the `Index.html`, but the problem is: `$(window).on("gMapsLoaded", initialize);` doesn't recognize the `initialize` function. I think that I'm in a dilemma.

Comment: Where is initialize defined?

Comment: There's an `Index.html` and there's an `ui.js`. Initialize is defined within `ui.js` when the click is triggered.

Comment: If you define it on the window, it should be available everywhere. `window.initialize = function () {...};`

Comment: WOW! It works! To pass the custom address I defined `var address;` in the `Index.html` and then, on the trigger`, I set up its value. Thank you very much, @KevinB! You helped me a lot: not just with my question, but with JavaScript in general. Thank you! +1